# How to pass records to the other page on custom qweb report for account.invoice ( Odoo V11 )?

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb, odoo-11, odoo-view

I have a custom report template with header and footer

I extended this header and this footer from "web.external_layout_standard"

How can I specify the number of record on the report page.

For example, I want products to switch to the other page after 16th. I have problems like the picture.

Picture link:
https://i.hizliresim.com/8YZDMk.png

I am trying this codes but not working correctly:

```
<t t-if="counter==16 and line['price_subtotal']">
      <tr class="text-right" style="border:0;border-top:0">
         <td colspan="6">
           <strong>Ara Toplam:</strong>
             <span>
               <t t-esc="subtotal" t-options="{'widget':'monetary', 
                                 'display_currency':o.currency_id}"/>
             </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <t t-set="counter" t-value="0" />
      <div style="page-break-after:auto;"></div>
</t>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<t t-set="count" t-value="0"/>
<t t-set="page" t-value="16"/>
<t t-foreach="your_loop_variable" t-as="c">
    <t t-if="counter==16 and line['price_subtotal']">
      <tr class="text-right" style="border:0;border-top:0">
         <td colspan="6">
           <strong>Ara Toplam:</strong>
             <span>
               <t t-esc="subtotal" t-options="{'widget':'monetary', 
                                 'display_currency':o.currency_id}"/>
             </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <t t-set="counter" t-value="0" />
      <t t-set="count" t-value="count+1" />
      <t t-if="count==page">
        <p style="page-break-after:auto;"></p>
        <t t-set="page" t-value="page+16" />
      </t>
    </t> 
</t>
```

- Please try this code :